# CloudKit operations execute in development version but sometimes hang in production version

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

I make calls to the iCloud database in two different ways in my app:

1.
Calling a `CKDatabase` convenience method works perfectly in development (simulator) and production (device) environments:

```
let privateDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase

privateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(recordID, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in
    // handle record and errors
})
```

2.
Adding `CKOperations` to the main queue works perfectly in the development environment, and works for a while when I test in the production environment - but then arbitrarily, after a few hours of intermittent testing, this call to the database just starts hanging - no errors are produced, and no completion code is executed. (The `fetchRecordWithID` call still works perfectly all the time.)

```
let op1 = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
op1.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error) -> Void in
    // handle records and errors
    }
op1.database = privateDatabase

// let op2, op3...

NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperations([
    op1,
    op2,
    op3,
    ], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

In the Usage panel in the CloudKit dashboard, nothing is even remotely approaching a limit. What other variables am I not considering - or what other tests can I run to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: try setting the op1, op2 and op3.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the op1, op2 and op3.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated

That setting has been set to a 'lower' standard value in iOS 9.

The documentation states for the qualityOfService:

> The relative amount of importance for granting system resources to the
>   operation. Service levels affect the priority with which an operation
>   object is given access to system resources such as CPU time, network
>   resources, disk resources, and so on. Operations with a higher quality
>   of service level are given greater priority over system resources so
>   that they may perform their task more quickly. You use service levels
>   to ensure that operations responding to explicit user requests are
>   given priority over less critical work. This property reflects the
>   minimum service level needed to execute the operation effectively. The
>   default value of this property is
>   `NSOperationQualityOfServiceBackground` and you should leave that value
>   in place whenever possible. When changing the service level, use the
>   minimum level that is appropriate for executing the corresponding
>   task. For example, if the user initiates a task and is waiting for it
>   to finish, assign the value `NSOperationQualityOfServiceUserInitiated`
>   to this property. The system may give the operation a higher service
>   level to the operation if the resources are available to do so.

Comment: background is supposed to hold your request until the device's radio is powered up for example.